# Wrong site rendering on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile

Here the problem. Page renders with strange artifacts at the bottom, but only on mobile devices and only in portrait mode. I suggest it causes with wrong wrapper design. Here some css:

```
   html {
       height: 100%;
       box-sizing: border-box;
   }

   *,
   *:before,
   *:after {
      box-sizing: inherit;
   }

   body {
      justify-content: center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      min-width: 1260px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding-top: 70px;
   }
```

And looks it something like this:

[image]

[Here's the site on production](http://vsteams.org)

Comment: What artefacts do you mean? Are they visible in the picture? Is it the graphic, or the white rectangle?

Comment: I marked artefacts place on picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was viewport problem. I still don't know why, but we need to limit viewport

> minimum-scale=1.0

for proper rendering

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
```

add this to header